# Как выбрать input элемент у которого значение в data содержит переменную?

Tags: jquery, input

```
<input type="button" data-option-value="aaaazzzz">

var inptdt = 'aaaazzzz';
$('input').data(inptdt).click(function () {
   alert(inptdt);
});
```

Мне надо чтобы при клике на input в data-option-value которого содержится переменная inptdt выполнялась функция. Как это грамотно написать? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: `$("input[data-option-value=....]")`

Comment: @DenKuzmin Вы что-то всё в кучу смешали, я так понимаю нужно сперва записать значение переменной в DOM (хотя это делается по другому) и также объявить функцию при клике которая бы работала с этим значением?

Comment: Как в эту конструкцию вписать переменную? $("input[data-option-value=inptdt]") ищет <input data-option-value="inptdt">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, вы хотите что-то такое:

```js
var inptdt = 'aaaazzzz';

// чтобы обратиться к элементу, найти его, задайте id или class, при этом помните, что id уникален на странице, а class может дублироваться, ниже я обращаюсь по id и записываю в него переменную
$('#input1').data('option-value', inptdt);
// $('#input1').attr('data-option-value', inptdt); // схожий метод

$('#input1').click(function() {
  alert($(this).data('option-value'));
  // alert($(this).attr('data-option-value')); // схожий метод
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input1" type="button" data-option-value="aaaazzzz" value="Кнопочка">
```

Comment: Да, именно так. Спасибо большое!

Comment: @DenKuzmin в таком случае прошу засчитать ответ и закрыть вопрос.

Comment: Подскажите ещё, пожалуйста, как обратиться к элементу, который содержит в name ту же переменную?

Comment: @DenKuzmin `$('input[name="aaaazzzz"]').data('option-value');` так вы можете получить данные атрибута `data-option-value` Советую вам прочесть справочник команд jQuery, там вы быстро поймете на примерах

Comment: @DenKuzmin Также могу посоветовать хороший [обучающий сайт](http://www.wisdomweb.ru/JQ/jquery-first.php)

Comment: Спасибо, а как в name подставить переменную?

Comment: @DenKuzmin Аналогично примера выше `$('input[name="aaaazzzz"]').data('option-value', inptdt);`